# Can't connect to Facebook?

Tags: tiny-tower

I've heard you could do it, but:

- In "Game center" in "settings" on my phone, it said that I wasn't signed into Facebook so I did.
- I'm signed in but it still says I'm not.

Any help?

Comment: How does this question have to do anything with video games

Comment: @stizzle84 The user tagged the question with "tiny-tower" so he wants to know how to connect to facebook in tiny tower.

Comment: It's a little absurd to see this question title on a gaming Q&A site...